# Access Query Remove Consecutive Duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

MyTable is like this:

| Invoice | Status | StatusDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 08:32AM |
| 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 08:43AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 09:52AM |
| 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 10:32AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 11:32AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 11:41AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 11:43AM |
| 1023 | Shipped | 2020-10-01 11:55AM |
| 1024 | Started | 2020-10-01 9:38AM |
| 1024 | Cancelled | 2020-10-01 11:15AM |

My desired result is:

| Invoice | Status | StatusDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 08:32AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 09:52AM |
| 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 10:32AM |
| 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 11:32AM |
| 1023 | Shipped | 2020-10-01 11:55AM |
| 1024 | Started | 2020-10-01 9:38AM |
| 1024 | Cancelled | 2020-10-01 11:15AM |

****Where grouped within an invoice, if a status repeats consecutively, only the oldest status is retained. The complexity is that the statuses may repeat inconsecutively, so I cannot just group on status and take the oldest status.****

Comment: i fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

For consecutive duplicates.

1.Calculate previous StatusDateTime for every row (qrInvStatusPrevTime) - lag(StatusDateTime).
2.Join with original table and get current and previous status (qrInvStatusWithPrev) - lag(Status).
3.Filter output for `Status<>PreviousStatus` or `PreviousStatus is Null`- no previous row.

```
SELECT qrInvStatusWithPrev.Id
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.Invoice
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.Status
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.StatusDateTime
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.PrevStatus
FROM (
      SELECT qrInvStatusPrevTime.Id
            , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Invoice
            , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Status
            , qrInvStatusPrevTime.StatusDateTime
            , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Prev_StatusDateTime
            , InvStatus.Status AS PrevStatus
      FROM (
             ( SELECT InvStatus.Id, InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status, InvStatus.StatusDateTime
                     ,Max(IIF(InvStatus_1.StatusDateTime<[InvStatus].[StatusDateTime]
                           ,InvStatus_1.StatusDateTime,null) ) AS Prev_StatusDateTime
               FROM InvStatus 
               LEFT JOIN InvStatus AS InvStatus_1 
                      ON InvStatus.Invoice = InvStatus_1.Invoice
               GROUP BY InvStatus.Id, InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status, InvStatus.StatusDateTime
                ) qrInvStatusPrevTime 
              LEFT JOIN InvStatus 
                   ON (qrInvStatusPrevTime.Invoice = InvStatus.Invoice) 
                  AND (qrInvStatusPrevTime.Prev_StatusDateTime = InvStatus.StatusDateTime)) 
    )  AS qrInvStatusWithPrev
WHERE (((qrInvStatusWithPrev.Status)<>[qrInvStatusWithPrev].[PrevStatus])) 
OR (((qrInvStatusWithPrev.PrevStatus) Is Null));
```

Output

| Id | Invoice | Status | StatusDateTime | PrevStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 08:32:00.000 | null |
| 3 | 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 09:52:00.000 | Started |
| 4 | 1023 | Started | 2020-10-01 10:32:00.000 | Production |
| 5 | 1023 | Production | 2020-10-01 11:32:00.000 | Started |
| 8 | 1023 | Shipped | 2020-10-01 11:55:00.000 | Production |
| 9 | 1024 | Started | 2020-10-01 09:38:00.000 | null |
| 10 | 1024 | Cancelled | 2020-10-01 11:15:00.000 | Started |

[There fiddle on SQL Server with Access compatible syntax](https://dbfiddle.uk/bmPe-cmb)

You can create this Query by MS Access query constructor, dividing this one on 3 part.
Main query

```
SELECT qrInvStatusWithPrev.Id
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.Invoice
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.Status
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.StatusDateTime
     , qrInvStatusWithPrev.PrevStatus
FROM  qrInvStatusWithPrev
WHERE (((qrInvStatusWithPrev.Status)<>[qrInvStatusWithPrev].[PrevStatus])) 
OR (((qrInvStatusWithPrev.PrevStatus) Is Null));
```

SubQuery1: qrInvStatusWithPrev

```
SELECT qrInvStatusPrevTime.Id
     , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Invoice
     , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Status
     , qrInvStatusPrevTime.StatusDateTime
     , qrInvStatusPrevTime.Prev_StatusDateTime
     , InvStatus.Status AS PrevStatus
FROM qrInvStatusPrevTime 
LEFT JOIN InvStatus 
       ON (qrInvStatusPrevTime.Invoice = InvStatus.Invoice) 
      AND (qrInvStatusPrevTime.Prev_StatusDateTime = InvStatus.StatusDateTime) 
 ;
```

Subquery2 qrInvStatusPrevTime

```
SELECT InvStatus.Id, InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status
     ,InvStatus.StatusDateTime
     ,Max(IIF(InvStatus_1.StatusDateTime<[InvStatus].[StatusDateTime]
                           ,InvStatus_1.StatusDateTime,null) ) AS Prev_StatusDateTime
FROM InvStatus 
LEFT JOIN InvStatus AS InvStatus_1 
          ON InvStatus.Invoice = InvStatus_1.Invoice
GROUP BY InvStatus.Id, InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status, InvStatus.StatusDateTime
;
```

Upd: This is first example, for first status. After@topsail comment, I'l update my answer for consecutive statuses.

```
SELECT InvStatus.Id, InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status 
   , InvStatus.StatusDateTime
FROM InvStatus 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status
        , Min(InvStatus.StatusDateTime) AS [Min-StatusDateTime]
    FROM InvStatus
    GROUP BY InvStatus.Invoice, InvStatus.Status
  ) as qrMinDate 
ON (InvStatus.Invoice = qrMinDate.Invoice)  
 AND (InvStatus.Status = qrMinDate.Status)  
 AND (InvStatus.StatusDateTime = qrMinDate.[Min-StatusDateTime])
;
```

Comment: I do not have an Id field in my table

Comment: The Id field does not matter. I entered it only to show which rows remain after the filter. You can delete it from the query.

Answer (score -1):

The rows you want are the ones with a status different of the previous one when partitioning by invoice and ordering by date:

```
select Invoice, Status, StatusDateTime
from (
    select d.*, decode(status, lag(status) over(partition by invoice order by StatusDateTime), null, 1) as first_one
    from InvStatus d
)
where first_one = 1
;
```

Comment: MS Access SQL does not support `partition` .

Comment: You added the tag msaccess after the answer.

Comment: no, ms-access tag was there with original question. also says access in question